# Acer Aspire One 722 Touchpad Too Sensitive After Upgrade

Tags: 11.10, kernel, touchpad, acer, aspire-one

I just recently got an AO722 and installed Ubuntu 11.10.  I was aware of some of the problems with the net-book so I set about tweaking things accordingly.

I followed many of the instructions here (specifically the net boot and graphics instructions):

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/202-ubuntu-acer-ao722

and here (specifically the Jupiter and power regression instructions):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811178

Last night, while installing and going through an update/upgrade, I noticed there were a lot of packages being held back.  Included were the new Linux kernal and a whole mess of xorg stuff so I did a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  The kernal is 3.0.0-17-generic.

After reboot, the touchpad behaved differently.  It is much more sensitive and the pointer is much more difficult to control on the screen.  Adjusting the sensitivity and acceleration in system settings does not help so I think something was broken with my last upgrade.  I've been looking around on the Internet and have found nothing about this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you update to 12.04 ? I would post on the forums thread you listed in your question, seems to be an active community.

Comment: No, I'm still running 11.10

Answer (score 1):

As I had just installed 11.10 on my 722 and didn't have any personal stuff on it, I decided to install 12.04beta after bodhi.razen mentioned it.

So far, I haven't had any problems at all and, important for this question, my touchpad problem has gone away!

While not really a fix, upgrading to 12.04 did solve my problem.

Comment: Did you have to do anything extra like you did in 11.10/11.04 to get ubuntu work happily with AO 722?

Comment: I just did a standard upgrade -- no clean install.  I still have the network boot hack, open source graphics drivers, and Jupiter running.